# A type with declaration but without definition used throughout many packages

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have just started my adventure with Oracle and PL/SQL by analysing some legacy code.

I came across the following declaration which does not seem to have any definition (BODY)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TY_STRING_T";
```

but is used in many places throughout many packages. For example like this.

```
otc ty_string_t := ty_string_t();
```

I understand that this is like creation of an instance of class `ty_string_t`.

Then it is used for example as a collection.

```
otc.EXTEND;
otc(1) := 'test';
```

How come that this type is used that way while there is no definition of it at all? What am I missing? In SQL Developer under types there is no body part when I extend the node.

EDIT:

Searching for the dependencies in `all_dependencies` table gives the following result.

```
SELECT * FROM all_dependencies WHERE name = `TY_STRING_T`;
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| OWNER | NAME        | TYPE | REFERENCED_OWNER | REFERENCED_NAME | REFERENCED_TYPE | REFERENCED_LINK_NAME | DEPENDENCY_TYPE |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| AAA   | TY_STRING_T | TYPE | SYS              | STANDARD        | PACKAGE         | (null)               | HARD            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an overriding definition in your package(s), so you have a PL/SQL type that takes precedence? Or in a different schema, perhaps, though that would be more obvious. Or that SQL-level type isn't redefined later? As far as I'm aware you can't do anything with an incomplete type except complete it with an object definition; but you aren't referring to it as an object type anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I will check them.

Comment: @AlexPoole Does it give you a compiler error if you try to define such a schema type and then use it in the given way?

Comment: [Yes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3007a/1); `PLS-00311: the declaration of "TY_STRING_T" is incomplete or malformed`. But I can [override the type](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3007a/2). Since you aren't showing a prefix, you'd have to define that in every package (spec) that uses it, so I would have thought it would be easy to spot. You can also look in `all_dependencies` to see if anything is actually using the SQL type.

Comment: A select on `all_dependencies` returns only one row, which I have just included in the question.

Comment: That just means your type depends on the standard package; do you se any record where `referenced_name` is your type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95327/discussion-between-jagger-and-alex-poole).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you show:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TY_STRING_T";
```

creates [an incomplete object type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8001.htm#SQLRF01506):

> Use the CREATE TYPE statement to create the specification of an **object type**, a **SQLJ object type**, a named varying array (**varray**), a **nested table type**, or an **incomplete object type**.

...

> An **incomplete type** is a type created by a forward type definition. It is called "incomplete" because it has a name but no attributes or methods. It can be referenced by other types, and so can be used to define types that refer to each other. However, you must fully specify the type before you can use it to create a table or an object column or a column of a nested table type.

The [object-relational developer's guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjmng.htm#ADOBJ7651) has more information about incomplete types and examples of using them.

That isn't what you have though. You are instantiating and populating a varray, not an object type. [It would not compile the PL/SQL code with the incomplete type](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3007a/1) - you would get an `PLS-00311: the declaration of "TY_STRING_T" is incomplete or malformed` compilation error.

From comments you do not have an overriding PL/SQL type and (from chat) the `all_dependencies` view confirms that your packages are dependent on the SQL-level type. But it can't be defined the way you think it is.

You can check the current actual definition of the type with

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TYPE', 'TY_STRING_T') from dual;
```

With the statement you showed that returns:

```
DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TYPE','TY_STRING_T')                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "STACKOVERFLOW"."TY_STRING_T" ;
```

Again from chat, when you run that you really see:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "AAA"."TY_STRING_T" as table of varchar2(32767);
```

which makes much more sense. Oracle won't have added the `as table...` part itself though - since it would have been happy leaving it as an incomplete object type; you just woudn't have been able to use it, certainly not as if it was a varray.

So some other part of your code base recreated the type with the new, full, definition; or someone manually recreated the type (before creating the packages that refer to it). If I had to speculate I'd think this might be a source code control problem - that incomplete code was checked in and shipped, and it had to be corrected on the fly in each environment as it was installed. Or possibly that the code had been changed after installation, to a version that is no longer correct.

The type name suggests it was always supposed to be a table of strings though, not an object type; and the truncated version of the create command that you found would never have actually created a varray.

You aren't really missing anything in your understanding, it's just that what you are looking at doesn't reflect reality.

Comment: You are quick. I was hunting for the documentation where it says "*or an incomplete object type*" +1

Comment: Question : Doesn't the generated metadata shows you as **EDITIONABLE TYPE**. On my 12c, `SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TYPE', 'TY_STRING_T') from dual;


DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TYPE','TY_STRING_T')
--------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE "LALIT"."TY_STRING_T"`

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I'm still on 11g and doesn't there; I copied and pasted from SQL Developer. No, it was added in 12c; [11g docs without](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8001.htm), and [12c docs with](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8001.htm) the editionable/noneditionable clause. That isn't mentioned in the [changes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/release_changes.htm).

Comment: I got the difference, I updated in my answer. Perhaps something changed in 12c. Okay, i see your edited comment. Thanks for the pointer. I don't see it is mentioned in the new features in 12c. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LalitKumarB - that doesn't have anything to do with the question though? I thought SYS objects couldn't be editionable anyway, but can't find a reference; either way default depends on whether the schema has editions enabled? Going rather off-topic though... (Something for a blog post? *8-)

Comment: Yeah, not related to current topic. Got carried away. Removed the noise.

Comment: "*Something for a blog post?*" hmm good idea. It would go [here](http://lalitkumarb.com/category/oracle-12c-installation-new-features/) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oracle-database-app-admin/category/Oracle+12c+Installation+%26+New+Features)

Answer (score 0):

> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "AAA"."TY_STRING_T"

The above type creation is incomplete.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TY_STRING_T"
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2  otc ty_string_t := ty_string_t();
  3  BEGIN
  4  otc.EXTEND;
  5  otc(1) := 'test';
  6  end;
  7  /
otc ty_string_t := ty_string_t();
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00311: the declaration of "TY_STRING_T" is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Reading the chat between OP and @AlexPoole,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TY_STRING_T" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767)
/
```

makes more sense.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TY_STRING_T" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767)
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2  otc ty_string_t := ty_string_t();
  3  BEGIN
  4  otc.EXTEND;
  5  otc(1) := 'test';
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```